# 'nach Juli' or 'nach dem Juli'?

Tags: preposition, article

In English it's 'after July' but not 'after the July'. I wonder if it's the same in German. Do people say 'nach Juli' or 'nach dem Juli'?

Comment: Can you give more context?

Comment: @PMF I am doing some revision of notes from years ago. In the section under Datum, there is an example: 'im/vor dem/nach dem Juli'. I find this saying a bit strange so I googled it but couldn't find any result related to 'nach Juli' or 'nach dem Juli'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*vor/nach dem + <kbd>month</kbd>* is uncommon, *vor + <kbd>month</kbd>* is common, *nach + <kbd>month</kbd>* is rare, but not wrong.

Samples:

> - Vor Juli wird das Gerät nicht geliefert.
> - Vor Juli 2024 komme ich nicht nach Europa zurück.

> - 2017 und 2018 zahlreiche, einige später, aber nach Juli 2019 wurden ihm keine Straftaten mehr nachgewiesen.
> - Nach Juli kommt August.

Comment: Dates, however, are generally used with the article: "Vor dem 12. Juli muss das Projekt fertig sein"